# Как открыть файл в эмуляторе Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Как открыть файл в эмуляторе Android Studio? Не могу открыть файл в эмуляторе. IDE сообщает, что не может создать директорию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все разобрался, WindowsDefender блокировал эмулятор и не давал ему создать файл в своем каталоге. Просто необходимо внести в исключения qemu-system-x86_64.exe